# SSRS Date question using Globals!ExecutionTime

Tags: reporting-services

Hi I am trying to print  a report in SSRS with two dates in the header. the first date will be dated one week ago and the second will be todays date..

I can't seem to figure out how to get the date for one week ago working.. I have tried

```
**Globals!ExecutionTime - 7**
```

as the expression but it does not work. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=DateAdd("d", -7, Globals!ExecutionTime)
```